# Create a variable that contains an action

Tags: c#, wpf, function, variables, var

I'am trying to do a variable that when I call it, that execute a code.

For example

```
string path1;
string path2;

bool check;

var make;// the variable in case

//other code

if(check == false)
{
 make = File.Copy(path1, path2); // the thing impossible to do
}
else
{
 make = File.Move(path1, path2);
}

make;//and here it should to run some code
```

This does not run the code that is contained in *make*.

But the code **mustn't** use an internal compiler, as Roslyn, because it is too slow.

I've try as this but doesn't work:

```
Action make = File.Copy(path1, path2);
```

I **don't** want to use a function as:

```
public void main()
{
  make();
}


public void make()
{
 if(check == false)
 {
  make = File.Copy(path1, path2);
 }
 else
 {
  make = File.Move(path1, path2);
 }
}
```

It's possible to do this? Thank

Comment: See [`Action`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.action) and [`Action<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.action-1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need is to harness the power of delegates, your goal can simply be achieved using this code:

```
string path1;
string path2;

bool check;

Action make = null;// the variable in case

//other code

if(check == false)
{
 make = () => File.Copy(path1, path2); // the thing impossible to do
}
else
{
 make = () => File.Move(path1, path2);
}

make();//and here it should to run some code
```

Answer (score 3):

You were so super close. It was just an issue of getting the syntax right.

Here it is:

```
Action make;

if (check == false)
{
    make = () => File.Copy(path1, path2);
}
else
{
    make = () => File.Move(path1, path2);
}

make();
```

`Action` (as opposed to `Action<T>` or `Action<T1, T2>` for example) takes no parameters so you must indicate this with the empty parameters using `() =>`.

Answer (score -2):

I think you can resolve it through the using of delegates, a delegate is can reference to a method
Here's a link https://www.bing.com/videos/search?q=c%23+delegate&docid=608021580906889596&mid=8AA2F8B388EE3F6D24718AA2F8B388EE3F6D2471&view=detail&FORM=VIRE about the using of delegates

Comment: Please do not post "link-only" answers. Put the salient content in your answer and only link to provide supporting evidence.